# Maven partial archetype to change existing file

Tags: maven

I am generating a file created using a maven archetype, call it example.xml. Is there any way to change (or append new code to) the content of this file using partial archetypes.

**For example:**

Suppose that `example.xml` contains nothing when generated.

When generating a partial archetype `editExampleToIncludeA`, it updates the file `example.xml` to include a new element, call it A.

And when I generate a partial archetype `editExampleToIncludeB` it updates `example.xml` by adding in a new element B (and retaining element A)